# Generate list by its upper bounds

Tags: python, list

I would like to generate the following type of list.

Input `2,5`

Output

```
[1,1],[1,2]

[2,1],[2,2]

[3,1],[3,2]

[4,1],[4,2]

[5,1],[5,2]
```

i.e. let each index run from 1 to its upper bound I can use loops, as

```
for i in range(1,3)

for j in range (1,6)

....
```

But it becomes increasingly awkward when the input becomes `[1,2,3,4,5]...`

E.g.

Input

```
[2,3,4]
```

Output

```
[1,1,1] [1,1,2] [1,1,3] [1,1,4]

[1,2,1] [1,2,2] [1,2,3] [1,2,4]

[1,3,1] [1,3,2] [1,3,3] [1,3,4]

[2,1,1] [2,1,2] [2,1,3] [2,1,4]

[2,2,1] [2,2,2] [2,2,3] [2,2,4]

[2,3,1] [2,3,2] [2,3,3] [2,3,4]
```

Input

```
[1,2,3]
```

Output

```
[1,1,1] [1,1,2] [1,1,3]

[1,2,1] [1,2,2] [1,2,3]
```

Is there any elegant way of doing that? (preferably in python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert them all to `range`s and use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Star unpacking makes it easy to do:

```
allranges = (range(1, lim+1) for lim in inputs)
for prod in itertools.product(*allranges):
    print(prod)
```